# zip multiple files with whitespace shell script

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I need to zip multiple files into one zip file. I need to preserve the directory structure of files in the zip file as well. The files to be zipped will be in a separate text file with full path. I read the file names from the text file into a variable and pass it to the zip command. Here is the command i use.

```
zip -r $EXP_DIR/Export_files.zip $BASE_DIR -i "$file_name"
```

It works fine for single file. But when i add multiple files it fails with the below error.

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (zip file name)
```

I do not understand what i am missing here. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: what is the value of $file_name?

Comment: i read the text file containing files to be zipped loop through it and append it to file_name

Answer (score 2):

1) `myfile.txt` contains filenames delimited by newline

```
zip out.zip -@ < myfile.txt
```

2) `myfile.txt` contains filenames delimited by whitespace (no whitespace allowed in filenames!)

```
zip out.zip -@ < <(tr ' ' '\n' < myfile.txt)
```

From [`man zip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

> *If a file list is specified as `-@` [Not on MacOS], zip takes the list*
>   *of input files from standard input instead of from the command line.*
>   *For example, `zip -@ foo` will store the files listed one per line on stdin in `foo.zip`*

Comment: Thank you, this works. But the only problem is it is not preserving the directory structure of the files. I would need the zip file containing the directory structure as well. For example if my files are in /test/doc1/file 1.txt , /test/doc2/file 2.txt, the zip file should contain the files along with the directory structure. That was the reason i zipped the entire directory and used -i to include only the files from the text file

Comment: @Gunasekaran: the `-r` option tells `zip` to recurse into directories. Since all your input is a series of filenames, how can this flag help you? DO you need to store all files in absolute path?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. This works as expected. Thank you very much.